# how to install mongodb on unix server

Tags: mongodb, unix

I want to install mango DB in FreeBSD sever.In mango DB documents they are not telling about UNIX servers.

Please let me know the step by step guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link for that:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-freebsd-10-1
But since links-alone is poor stackoverflow.com protocol, this is essence of what you need to do when logged in on that server:

```
sudo pkg update -f
sudo pkg install mongodb
sudo service mongod start
```

P.S.  mongo, not mango.